# Deleted by mistake

Tags: delete, undelete

I deleted a huge folder containing mp3 & mp4 songs by mistake. I thought it will be in trash but when I opened it, the folder wasn't there but when I opened the properties of trash I saw that it contained +2000 folders of 55 GB. The files are not visible somehow. Can you please tell me how to recover it? I don't want this huge loss of my favourite items.

Comment: How did you delete them? and do you have a backup at all?

Comment: It might be that the Trash folder is now so large it takes a long time to load - so you could open the Trash folder and see if it loads

Comment: @Wilf, sorry too used to chat!

Comment: @Wilf sometimes a dialouge says "This file is to large to be moved to trash, do you want to permanently delete it". Did this pop up @Annie?

Comment: Does anything appear in `ls -lh ~/.local/share/Trash/files/`?

Comment: I deleted by mistake. :(

Comment: @Wilf No no such thing appeared.

Comment: What is Nautilius? How can i use it?

Comment: Nautilus is the the default file explorer.

Comment: Where do i find it from?

Comment: The program that you deleted it from, that is nautilus. You probably call it files or something?

Comment: Can you press ctrl+alt+t?

Comment: when i press ctrl+alt+t  a command screen appears what next

Comment: Data recovered. Thank you for the assistance. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can view hidden files in Nautilus using the keyboard combo <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd>. Or using the menu: select View->Show Hidden Files.

If the files were deleted from an external drive they may be on that drive in a `.trash` hidden directory

As a ditch effort; if you know the name of a file (a good unique name) you can use the following to search the whole filesystem

`sudo find / -iname "*<good file name>*"`

`<good file name>` should be replace with a filename but keep the `*` on each side

That will take a while to run.